# How to use requests to send a PATCH request with headers

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests

I have a Rails 4 application which uses token based authentication for APIs and need to be able to update records through Python 3 script.

My current script looks like this

```
import requests
import json

url = 'http://0.0.0.0:3000/api/v1/update_experiment.json'
payload = {'expt_name' : 'A60E001', 'status' : 'done' }

r = requests.patch(url, payload)
```

which works OK if I disable API authentication.

I can't figure out how to add headers to it, `requests.patch` only takes two parameters according to docs.

I would need to get to the point where the following header info would added

```
'Authorization:Token token="xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"'
```

This type of header works OK in curl. How can I do this in Python 3 and requests?

Comment: Did you actually *try* adding `headers=`? What happened?

Comment: I tired something like `headers= {'Authorization': 'Token', 'token': 'xxxxxx' }`
then `r = requests.patch(url, payload, headers=headers)` but nothing happens, no error in Python, no reaction from WebRick on Rails side. Trying to play with logs to see what it going on.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

[patch](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/_modules/requests/api/#patch) takes kwargs, just pass headers = {your_header}:

```
def patch(url, data=None, **kwargs):
    """Sends a PATCH request.

    :param url: URL for the new :class:`Request` object.
    :param data: (optional) Dictionary, bytes, or file-like object to send in the body of the :class:`Request`.
    :param \*\*kwargs: Optional arguments that ``request`` takes.
    :return: :class:`Response <Response>` object
    :rtype: requests.Response
    """

    return request('patch', url,  data=data, **kwargs)
```

So something like this:

```
head = {"Authorization":"Token token=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"}
url = 'http://0.0.0.0:3000/api/v1/update_experiment.json'
payload = {'expt_name' : 'A60E001', 'status' : 'done' }

r = requests.patch(url, payload, headers=head)
```

Comment: Hi. I tried `headers= {'Authorization': 'Token', 'token': 'xxxxxx' }` then `r = requests.patch(url, payload, headers=headers)` but Rails doesn't seem to like this. Authentication fails. How can I see what Python is actually sending, how to inspect the header. I tied `print(r.headers)` but this doesn't include any of the info I passed in as headers.

Comment: @BartC note that that isn't quite the format of the headers - re-read that last code snippet.

Comment: @PadraicCunningham Enormous Thanks!!!!, that worked great, missed that detail / just didn't get it which was the culprit all along in many of my other attempts to make it work. Thanks again.